# Finding an equation for a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $a = \begin{bmatrix} 1; & −1; & 1;\end{bmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{bmatrix} 2; & 1; & 3;\end{bmatrix}$.  Let $W$ be the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ defined by $W = \{x : a^T x = 0\ \text{and}\ b^T x = 0\}$.

Find an equation for $W$.

Comment: I understand that W must be orthogonal to both of the fixed vectors a and b in R3, however I do not understand how to use this information to create an equation for the subspace.

Comment: I don't understand: your defining relations *are* equations. Btw $W$ requires two equations.

Comment: The question asked is acting as if there is a single equation to find. I can explain the relations, but I do not fully understand how that translates to an equation on paper

Answer (score 0):

The space $W$ is spanned by all vectors that are orthoganal to $a$ and orthogonal to $b$. Note that the vector $c:= a \times b$ is orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$. All vectors $\lambda c$ for an arbitrary real number $\lambda$ are also orthogonal to both $a,b$.

Comment: Yeah, the span of W makes sense to me. I am just unsure of what to do with that info to make an equation for the subspace since I've never really done anything like that before

Comment: You define a Parameter $\lambda$ and then you can list all vectors $x$ in dependence on $\lambda$ with $x \in W$. Hint: $x= \lambda v$ with a constant vector $v$. What must $v$ be?

Comment: Would v in this case be 0?

Comment: v is equal to the cross product of a and b; other vectors don't satisfy the conditions for lying in $W$.

Comment: Oh right, right. So their cross product would have to be 0 right? Since they would need to be parallel for the relationship above to be true?

Comment: $(a \times b)_z = a_x b_y - a_y b_x =1*1-(-1)*2=3$. The cross product of a and b is not Zero.

Comment: But if any x in W is everywhere orthogonal to both a and b wouldn't they have to be parallel? I get that their cross product disproves that but this is where I am getting stuck